# Getting center of a window from a Graphics object?

Tags: c#, graphics

I am making a simple way of "overlaying" games in C#, and this approach works, but I want to get the "center" of the window (X,Y) with the Graphics object I get. (not based on Screen res?) I tried looking for a method on MSDN, but couldn't find a way to do it.

```
String UserGameWindow = TextBox1.Text;
IntPtr gameWindow = FindWindow(null, UserGameWindow); //"GameWindow" is replaced by the window the user selects.
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(gameWindow))
{
    //Getting the "center" of the window (X,Y) from the Graphics object not dependent on screen resolution?
}
```

Comment: You could try Graphics.ClipBounds and calculate the center based on rectangle you get.

Comment: _The unit for resulting rectangle is designated by the PageUnit property.The default unit is pixels.A Graphics is typically associated with a control and the origin of the rectangle will be relative to the client area of that control.

If the clipping region is infinite, the ClipBounds property returns a meaningless large rectangle.To determine whether the clipping region is infinite, retrieve the Clip property and call its IsInfinite method._